# How to get Side-by-side layout in Beyond Compare 4's Picture Compare

Tags: images, diff, beyondcompare

Beyond Compare 4's Picture Compare has 2 images on top and the composite image below. This suits landscape images, but wastes plenty of space for highly portrait images on 16:9 monitors:
[image: http://muhqu.de/snapz/IMG_7903.CR2_%3C--%3E_IMG_7903.jpg_-_Picture_Compare-20140508-121056.png]

This video and screenshot show it operating in side-by-side layout:
http://youtu.be/AKsbjFX4GN8
[image: http://youtu.be/AKsbjFX4GN8]
[image: http://www.gearbyte.com/software/3rdparty/images/PixCompare.jpg]

and the Picture Viewer plug-in for Beyond Compare 2 has "Side-by-side Layout" and "Over-under Layout" options:
http://scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=v2pixview
[image: http://scootersoftware.com/images/v2pixview2.png]

Is there a way to turn on Side-by-side layout in Beyond Compare 4's Picture Compare? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Compare 4's Picture Compare doesn't have the Beyond Compare 3's Side-by-side layout. The only way you can change the layout is by selecting **View > Full Screen** (F11).

In the Full Screen view, there is an icon in the top left corner you can click on to select between the left image, right image, and comparison. Hit **F11** or **Esc** to exit Full Screen.